# compress the horizontal line of real time graph

Tags: java, graph, jfreechart

I want to compress and store data of real time line graph I tried but not succeeded

```
public class DTest extends ApplicationFrame {

    javax.swing.Timer _timer;
    int nPoints = 200;
    float[] history;
    /** The most recent value added. */
    private float lastValue = (float) 100.0;
    DynamicTimeSeriesCollection dataset;
    JPanel content;
    private final ChartPanel chartPanel;

    public DTest(final String title) {

        super(title);
        history = new float[nPoints];
        dataset = new DynamicTimeSeriesCollection(
                1, nPoints, new Second()//here speed will set
                );

        dataset.setTimeBase(new Second(0,0,0,1,1,2000));
        dataset.addSeries(new float[]{0.0f}, 0, "S1");
        System.out.println("Series count = " + dataset.getSeriesCount());
        final JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
        chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        content = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

        final JButton btn = new JButton("Stop");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                _timer.stop();
            }
        });
        final JButton btn1 = new JButton("Run");
        btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // create new dataset and chart, set the new chart in the chartpanel


                //createChart(dataset);

                _timer.start();
            }
        });
        JComboBox comb = new JComboBox();
        comb.addItem("Select");
        comb.addItem("Joy Stick");

        content.add(chartPanel);//panel for chart
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        btnPanel.add(btn);
        btnPanel.add(btn1);
        btnPanel.add(comb);

        Container pane = getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        pane.add(content, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        pane.add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 270));
        //setContentPane(content);
        comb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            private float[] float_array;
            private int itemCount;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JComboBox jComb = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
                if (jComb.getSelectedItem().equals("Joy Stick")) {
                    System.out.println("Joy Stick is Pressed");
                    try {
                        float_array = new float[1];
                        float_array[0] = 0;
                        itemCount = 0;
                        dataset.appendData(float_array);
                        dataset.addSeries(new float[]{0.0f}, 0, "S1");
                        _timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1, new ActionListener() { // 500ms

                            private int resizes;
                            private int inserted;
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                                double factor = 0.90 + 0.2 * Math.random();
                                lastValue = lastValue * (float) factor;
                                float_array[0] = lastValue;
                                System.out.println("lastValue is " + lastValue);

                                inserted++;
                                if ( inserted % (resizes+1)==0 )
                                    dataset.appendData(float_array, itemCount++, 1);
                                history[itemCount] = lastValue;
                                if (itemCount >= nPoints - 1) {
                                    resizes++;
                                    DynamicTimeSeriesCollection newSet = new DynamicTimeSeriesCollection(1, nPoints, new Second());
                                    newSet.setTimeBase(new Second(0,0,0,2,2,2000));
                                    newSet.addSeries(new float[]{0.0f}, 0, "S1");
                                    itemCount /= 2;
                                    for (int i = 1; i < nPoints; i++) {
                                        history[i / 2] = history[i];
                                        float_array[0]=history[i / 2];
                                        newSet.appendData(float_array, i/2, 1);
                                        history[i] = 0;
                                    }
                                    chartPanel.setChart(createChart(newSet));
                                    dataset = newSet;
                                    chartPanel.repaint();
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        _timer.setRepeats(true);
                        _timer.start();

                    } catch (NullPointerException ne) {
                        System.out.println("NullPointer Exception" + ne.toString());
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {  ;

                }

            }
        });
    }

    private JFreeChart createChart(final XYDataset dataset) {
        final JFreeChart result = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
                "Dynamic Graph", "Time", "Value", dataset, true, true,
                false);
        final XYPlot plot = result.getXYPlot();
        ValueAxis axis = plot.getDomainAxis();
        //plot.setRangeAxis(WIDTH, axi)
        axis.setAutoRange(true);
        //axis.setFixedAutoRange(60.0); // 60 seconds
        axis = plot.getRangeAxis();
        axis.setRange(-100.0, 200.0);
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                try {
                    final DTest demo = new DTest("Dynamic Graph");
                    demo.pack();
                    RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);

                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
                    demo.setVisible(true);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind terribly elaborating (quite a bit) on just what you mean by "to compress and store data of real time line graph".  Then please elaborate on "I tried but not succeeded".  Usually the better the question, the better the answer.

Comment: suppose line start at 0 point and moves forward as long as line move forward the previous line value should not be disappeared but it should began to compress itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to set data and update JFreechart on every Click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776545/how-to-set-data-and-update-jfreechart-on-every-click)

Answer (score 0):

> …as the line moves forward, the previous line value should not disappear, but it should begin to compress itself.

The `Memory Usage` tab of the [demo](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html) does exactly what you describe.

Comment: I stuck at this point how to store the data that I am showing on real time graph.any Idea

Comment: Because it is designed to display the most recent data in a FIFO queue, `DynamicTimeSeriesCollection` is probably not the best choice for this. As an alternative, you might consider another subclass of `AbstractIntervalXYDataset`.